# numpy - shapes error when trying to compute cost function

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm taking the corsera course on machine learning. I'm trying to convert the first weeks cost function into python.

```
import numpy as np

def computeCost(X, y, theta):  
    inner = np.power(((X.dot(theta)) - y), 2)
    return np.sum(inner) / (2 * len(X))
```

It works in the beginning. However, when I start plotting it into a 3D space, the cost doesn't seem to work anymore.

I run this
`print(computeCost(X, y, [theta0_vals[0], theta1_vals[0]]))`

I get "30109.7923098" However, I should get "328.0929"

I tried this:

```
inner = np.power(((X * (theta.T)) - y), 2)
return np.sum(inner) / (2 * len(X))
```

I get a dimension error.

I tried this:

```
m = len(y)                  #number of training examples
#X = np.array([np.ones(m), X])      #I did this beofre calling the function
X = X.transpose()

theta = theta.transpose()
c = np.dot(X, theta)            #Matrix multiplication X*theta
c = c.transpose() - y
J = np.sum(c**2)/(2*m)          #Calculating cost
return J
```

I get the error: ValueError: shapes (2,97) and (1,2) not aligned: 97 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What's the shape of X and y?

Comment: Matrices dimensions are not match.Use reshape to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use reshape to fix matrix dimensions.My solution is like that

```
theta = theta - (alpha / m) * np.dot(X.T.reshape(2, 97), np.dot(X, theta).flatten() - y).reshape(2, 1)
```